# Laravel API not returning validation messages properly

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel as an API base, but I am struggling to show meaningful validator messages in my JSON response. I am using Laravel 8.

This is the response when my validator fails:

```
{
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"errors": {
    "image": [
        "validation.mimes"
    ]
}
}
```

But instead of the `validation.mimes` i want an actual meaningful message, like `The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.`.

I've tried overriding the exception in `Exceptions\Handler.php` but I still can't seem to access actual error messages?

```
protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        'errors' => $exception->errors()
    ], $exception->status);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is your locale configured in `config/app.php`?

Comment: @MrEduar its configured to 'en' -- i see thats the key that defines all the error messages in `validation.js`. Could it be that it cant access the js file because I am not using blade only json responses?

Comment: Your messages have to go in validation.php not validation.js. Should be in `resources\lang\en\validation.php`

Comment: Hmm yeah i seem to be missing those.. any way to autogenerate?

Comment: No, get it from the original repository.

Comment: Yup just ended up doing that. Thanks a lot!